# How can we check my browsers are up to date

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I am writing a script in python which will update the browser by enabling the registry settings. I need to know how can we check if my browser is "up to date" (Matching with the latest version), PROGRAMATICALLY.

Issues I have tried:
Open selenium web driver with older browser version and check the "About" page. but as soon as it updated it got failed, and again I have to depend on the version its like deadlock dependency.

Is there any programmatical way to check my browser is up to date or not, if not it can update it.

I'm not looking on the working code, but a step to do make it possible.

Targeting browsers: Firefox, Chrome, Edge Chromium.

Comment: I think your method to check "About" page makes sense. Why will it fail when the browser updated? When you open the "About" page, browsers will auto check updates. If the browser is up to date, it will show "xxx is up to date" on "About" page. I think you can use web driver to navigate to the "About" page, then wait for a while, then check if "xxx is up to date" is in the element.

Comment: Yeah it worked, selenium things. thanks.